# onmouseover function() to access all css background-image url() in HTML document?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, background-image, onmouseover, cssom

```js
const bg = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
bg.forEach(bgi => {
  const b = bgi.computedStyleMap();
  const c = b.get('background-image');

  c.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    const img = e.target.c;
    if (c) location.assign(c);
  });
});
```

```css
#n {
  background-position: 40% 45%;
}

.rap {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/rDDRGYE.jpg");
  background-attachment: sticky;
  background-position: 77% 45%;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 40%;
  color: lightcyan;
  background-color: slategrey;
}

.ra {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.boldmethod.com/images/blog/lists/2016/03/11-facts-about-the-harrier-jump-jet/4.jpg");
  background-attachment: sticky;
  background-position: 71% 90%;
  height: 630px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: slategrey;
}

.os {
  height: 4350px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: slategrey;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://files.yande.re/image/43e9ae14c74ba30fe78e66e30caea227/yande.re%20403366%20business_suit%20kono_subarashii_sekai_ni_shukufuku_wo%21%20megumin%20mishima_kurone%20raratina_dustiness_ford%20witch.jpg");
  width: 2820 px;
  height: 2050 px;
  background-position-y: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: azure;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://n.sinaimg.cn/sinacn10104/334/w1319h2215/20190107/c4a8-hrfcctn3630013.jpg" alt="guy" width="220" height="300" style="float:left; padding:20px">
<img src="https://n.sinaimg.cn/sinacn10104/334/w1319h2215/20190107/c4a8-hrfcctn3630013.jpg" alt="guy" width="220" height="300" style="float:left; padding:20px">
<img src="https://stat.dokusho-ojikan.jp/dab52813-fbde-4b44-bbb2-6eea12b5bb35.jpg" alt="guy" width="300" height="423" style="float:left">




<p>
  <div class="rap"></div>
</p>

<p>
  <div class="rap" id="n" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:1800px; top:16px"></div>
</p>

<img src="https://i.ibb.co/YjG8SgN/SG8ZEag.png" alt="guy" id="ki" width="367" height="644" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:930px; top:431px">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8f/a7/b9/8fa7b999f20538fe753013f69a8f441c.jpg" width="433" height="580" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:1300px; top:431px">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/82/59/86/82598611fcf7003ca9cbd146085c3c1e.jpg" width="362" height="453" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:560px; top:431px">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/AcodYxf.jpeg" width="183" height="229" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:300px">

<div class="os"></div>





<div class="ra"></div>
<p>
  <div class="ra" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:1900px; top:4798px"></div>
</p>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/AcodYxf.jpeg" alt="guy" width="285" height="160" style="float:left; position: absolute; left: 1700px; top:16px">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/AcodYxf.jpeg" alt="guy" width="285" height="160" style="float:left; position: absolute; left: 1700px; top:350px">
```

Basically, I'm trying to assign a mouseover function() for all background-image url()'s on an HTML document. I want to be able to access/trigger each background-image url(), as though it were clicking an href link, when I mouseover one.

I attempted to apply CSSImageValue, a subset of CSS Object Model (CSSOM). How do I get this code to work?

Comment: Why would a css property have an event listener.... You should be binding the event to the element, not the css property

Comment: your html is invalid....

Comment: @MisterJojo why?

Comment: @epascarello, I understand what you mean, especially regarding your 2nd sentence. I just needed help in doing so.

Comment: why? the lines number, the `<p>` balance, the link from nowhere...

Comment: You have asked this question *seven* times now. You would benefit hugely from a course on JS basics.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which does not have a `forEach` function. `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, which does have a `forEach` function.

Comment: It seems, if this code actually worked, that when you moused over an element with a background-image, it would navigate to that image. To say that would be an unexpected user experience would be putting it mildly.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what you are trying to accomplish, but you have many basic concepts wrong.

Below will select all the elements. It loops over the NodeList and checks to see if the element has the computed style. If it does not, it just ignores it. If it does, it adds an event listener to the element. When you mouse over the element, it logs the background image value.

Note: I did not fix the invalid HTML.

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll("*");
elems.forEach(elem => {
  const bgImg = elem.computedStyleMap().get('background-image');
  if (bgImg.value === 'none') return;
  elem.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    console.log(bgImg.toString());
  });
});
```

```css
#n {
  background-position: 40% 45%;
}

.rap {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/rDDRGYE.jpg");
  background-attachment: sticky;
  background-position: 77% 45%;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 40%;
  color: lightcyan;
  background-color: slategrey;
}

.ra {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.boldmethod.com/images/blog/lists/2016/03/11-facts-about-the-harrier-jump-jet/4.jpg");
  background-attachment: sticky;
  background-position: 71% 90%;
  height: 630px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: slategrey;
}

.os {
  height: 4350px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: slategrey;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://files.yande.re/image/43e9ae14c74ba30fe78e66e30caea227/yande.re%20403366%20business_suit%20kono_subarashii_sekai_ni_shukufuku_wo%21%20megumin%20mishima_kurone%20raratina_dustiness_ford%20witch.jpg");
  width: 2820 px;
  height: 2050 px;
  background-position-y: 80%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: azure;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://n.sinaimg.cn/sinacn10104/334/w1319h2215/20190107/c4a8-hrfcctn3630013.jpg" alt="guy" width="220" height="300" style="float:left; padding:20px">
<img src="https://n.sinaimg.cn/sinacn10104/334/w1319h2215/20190107/c4a8-hrfcctn3630013.jpg" alt="guy" width="220" height="300" style="float:left; padding:20px">
<img src="https://stat.dokusho-ojikan.jp/dab52813-fbde-4b44-bbb2-6eea12b5bb35.jpg" alt="guy" width="300" height="423" style="float:left">




<p>
  <div class="rap"></div>
</p>

<p>
  <div class="rap" id="n" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:1800px; top:16px"></div>
</p>

<img src="https://i.ibb.co/YjG8SgN/SG8ZEag.png" alt="guy" id="ki" width="367" height="644" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:930px; top:431px">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8f/a7/b9/8fa7b999f20538fe753013f69a8f441c.jpg" width="433" height="580" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:1300px; top:431px">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/82/59/86/82598611fcf7003ca9cbd146085c3c1e.jpg" width="362" height="453" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:560px; top:431px">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/AcodYxf.jpeg" width="183" height="229" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:300px">

<div class="os"></div>





<div class="ra"></div>
<p>
  <div class="ra" style="float:left; position: absolute; left:1900px; top:4798px"></div>
</p>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/AcodYxf.jpeg" alt="guy" width="285" height="160" style="float:left; position: absolute; left: 1700px; top:16px">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/AcodYxf.jpeg" alt="guy" width="285" height="160" style="float:left; position: absolute; left: 1700px; top:350px">
```

Comment: you answer mostly made sense. Sadly there was this error message: "message": "TypeError: elem.computedStyleMap is not a function",

Comment: @ManuelRoads You have that in you original code... It's [not terribly well supported](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_computedstylemap), Only in Chrome and Chromium-based browsers.

Comment: I only used it because you did. So if you need to support other browsers, you need to use `getComputedStyle` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: @epascarello regarding the javascript code you wrote for the mouseover function(), I got this error:

"Your file couldn’t be accessed
It may have been moved, edited or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Why didn't the page navigate to the background image in question?

Comment: well the property would have `url(https://example.com.foo.gif)` so not sure how it would go to it when it has url()

Comment: @epascarello isn't the point of location.assign() is to navigate to another page location? I replaced console.log() with location.assign() and still I got that "Err_file_not_found"

Comment: The string you are going to is `"url(https://example.com.foo.gif)"`.... It is not a valid url....